# How to locate a java class in a .sh file on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, shell, ubuntu

I want to run a .sh file named ubiqstart.sh. using java. Specifically, I just want to execute a java class when running this .sh file. But I keep getting this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.ubiq.update.MainEntry.` Seems like the system is not able to locate where the java class is at. However, when I directly type in and execute this command in terminal (under this exact directory), it runs perfectly.

The script I use in the .sh file is: `"../java/bin/java" -cp "./*" com.ubiq.update.MainEntry`.

I wonder what causes this conflict and what should I do to make my .sh file to do the same thing as directly running the script.

Comment: It seems the script uses relative directories for both the java executable and the classpath. Are you sure the current directory is correct when the script is run? Alternatively, you could use absolute paths instead of relative paths in the script.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, I am positive that my paths were correct. I will try to use absolute paths on Monday. Is the path gonna look like "//opt/Storage/java/bin/java" ?

Comment: It would begin with a single slash, not a double slash. What I asked was not were you sure about the paths, but were you sure about what the current directory was when the script was run. The relative paths will be relative to whatever the current directory is. Depending on how and where the script is run, the current directory could be something other than what you expect.

Comment: @DavidConrad I figured out what is going wrong: I need to include a space after "com.ubiq.update.MainEntry" Somehow nano auto generates an end of line so I need to include a space to differentiate the class path from the EOF. I don't know if that make sense but adding a space after the class path solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

When you are using older editors like vim or nano, just simply add a space after your classpath, like: `com.ubiq.update.MainEntry` . Especially if you convert the script from windows' .bat to Linux .sh